# How to create a predicate using RxJava2

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to learn Rxjava and still at a very basic level. I am looking for some guidance on the below problem.

I have these 2 Observables namely,

```
    fun getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds(): Observable<Long> {
        return ConnectableObservable.interval(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map { exoPlayer.currentPosition }
            .publish()
            .autoConnect()
    }

    fun getContentDurationInMilliseconds(): Observable<Long> {
        return ConnectableObservable.just(exoPlayer.duration)
            .publish()
            .autoConnect()
    }
```

Now I am trying to create a predicate from these. My requirement is when `getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds` reaches 70% of  `getContentDurationInMilliseconds` I would like to raise a boolean signal.

As you can see, from `getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds` the subscriber will get the new value after every 1000ms, now I will like to compare this value with the total duration which I get from `getContentDurationInMilliseconds`. When `getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds` value reaches 70% of `getContentDurationInMilliseconds`, will raise a boolean signal.

I know how I can do this without using RxJava but as looking for a way to do it in RxJava. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an `Observable<Boolean>` that emits every time one of the child observables emit, and for the Boolean to be true based on your predicate. This can be achieve as follows:

```
    // Emits items when either child observable emits
    fun isPlayheadPosition70PercentOfContentDuration(): Observable<Boolean> =
        Observables                                         // Helper class from RxKotlin package
            .combineLatest(                                 // Emit a Pair<Long, Long> of values from the
                getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds(),        // latest of the child observables
                getContentDurationInMilliseconds()
            )
            .map { (playheadPosition, contentDuration) ->   // Transform the item based on this function
                playheadPosition >= 0.7 * contentDuration   // (in this case, into a Boolean based on a predicate)
            }
```

Where `Observables` is a helper class with useful methods from [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), which is a nice-to-have when writing Rx in Kotlin.

I think perhaps you might also just want to trigger an event as soon as your predicate is satisfied. In this case, you can transform the above into a `Completable` that triggers when your predicate first becomes true:

```
    // If you subscribe to this, the onComplete will signal once the predicate is satisfied
    fun playheadPositionHasReached70PercentContentDuration(): Completable =
        Observables
            .combineLatest(getPlayheadPositionInMilliseconds(), getContentDurationInMilliseconds())

            // Filter: Only allow elements through the stream if they satisfy this predicate
            .filter { (playheadPosition, contentDuration) -> playheadPosition >= 0.7 * contentDuration }

            // Take only the first element (i.e. turn this into a Single)
            .firstOrError()

            // Actually, I don't care about the element, I just want to know when it happens
            // (i.e. turn this into a Completable)
            .ignoreElement()
```

Comment: So the first example is working fine. For the Completeable one, somehow I do not see it getting fired. That's how my subscriber is
```
playheadPositionHasReached70PercentContentDuration()
            .subscribeWith(object : CompletableObserver {
                override fun onComplete() {
                    // Do stuff
                    }
                }

                override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                }

            })
```